# Image storage and retrieval from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app in which I want to retrieve the images from the database and display it on widgets of [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/).For development purpose I want to create a variable of image in my javascript code as it will come from server, which I will then process it to convert it to image and display on widget.

My main question is what is the form of the image when retrieved from a server and what further processing I will need to do on it in javascript to get an actual image which I can display on images.

Comment: Can't you just retrieve the path of the image, and inject it as the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element? Unless you are talking about converting the image to base64 on the server side, streaming it to the client, and displaying it as `data-uri`. In one way or another, it is not entirely clear what you are asking for in the question--can you give some concrete examples?

Comment: Actually the backend is not ready at all.And I basically wanted the idea of how the images are stored (in what form) in the server.How they are when we retrieve them at front end and further what processing is required to convert the received data to an actual image

Comment: The images should be just stored as files: storing them as blobs in a database is somewhat counterintuitive. If you expect to store a lot of images, you might want to consider a third party file hosting service with a usable API. Your question is extremely broad though, so you might want to consider searching around a bit.

Comment: I read somewhere that images are converted to URL and then it is stored in the database.So If that's correct then I would convert an image to url(as it is stored in database/as it will be retrieved from database) again convert that URL to image and display then display it on widgets

Comment: But I am not sure that whether this is correct of not

Comment: You store the image either on file or in a db, then you access that image via `<img src='/path/to/image.jpg'>` - so it is *served* (ie from the server) as an image already.  If it's stored in a DB, then your url points to an endpoint and the server-side code extracts from the DB and returns the image content.  You don't load the image "into a variable" as it's harder to do anything with it then.

Answer (score 1):

To store images on a server, you'll just upload the image (for example: copy a file from your computer to the remote server), and save the local relative path to your image in the database.

So, when you want to retrieve it from the server, it will serve you the image path, like this :

```
{
  'image_path' => 'the/path/to/my/image.jpg'
  ... // other stuff
}
```

Then you just have to set the img src attribute with this value.